# java8 - pick last modified file using ChannelSftp pattern match

Tags: java, regex, collections, java-8, jsch

As I know `ChannelSftp.ls` takes as an argument as `Directory` and it lists the list of vectors, our project requirement is the find out last modified file from the matched glob pattern and move it to another directory, we can achieve it `string.contains()` the approach also, what is the simple way to do it in `Java-8`, `JSCH 0.1.51`. Below is the code which I am trying how can fix it to make it work

Directory list of files are like this:

- `xx_lastbird_20180909.txt`
- `xABBS_xxx_firstbird_20170609.txt`
- `xxxx_firstbird_20170609.txt`
- `xxxxx_firstbird_20150909.txt`

The code:

```
Vector ls = channelSftp.ls(path);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("*_[lastbird,firstbird]_[0-9]{8}.txt");

for (Object entry : ls) {
    ChannelSftp.LsEntry e = (ChannelSftp.LsEntry) entry;
    //match regex on e.getFilename()
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(e.getFilename());
    if (m.matches()) {
        // last modified file object from matched file names
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here Java-8 will not help you much. The date number is easily recognizable with [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/O2Vi6O/1):

```
\w+_\w+_(\d+)\.\w{2,4}
```

Just a note I suppose on the `xxxx` and `lastbird` are always 1..n letters divided with `_` separator and followed with another one. Then the numeric part representing a date comes. Finally a file extension including 2-4 letters.

Use this advantage to get the date (ex. `20170609`). Those could be parsed to integers and since this format allows a direct integer comparison, get the highest number.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+_\\w+_(\\d+)\\.\\w{2,4}");
Matcher matcher;

int maxIndex = 0;
int maxDate = 0;

for (int i=0; i<ls.size(); i++) {
    String filename = ((ChannelSftp.LsEntry) entry).getFilename();
    matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);
    if (matcher.find(1)) {
        int date = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        if (date >= maxDate) {
            date = maxDate;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Last modified file is found on index: " + maxIndex);
ChannelSftp.LsEntry = (ChannelSftp.LsEntry) vector.get(maxIndex);
```

Comment: Ok, How can I get a last modified file object.

Comment: *_[lastbird,firstbird]_[0-9]{8}.txt  what correction required in this pattern, becuase sub stirngs(lastbird, firstbird) always same for all files.?

Comment: I want last modfied file not the file date which is mentioned in file name

Comment: @user1272269: I have added a line describing a way to get the entry.

Comment: I dont see fileObj.lastModified() which give lastmodified time of it.

Comment: I don't see what `fileObj.lastModified()` has returned. Please edit the question and provide more information. I cannot answer you now.

Comment: In question itself I mentioned  // last modified file object ,It means the file object which is modified recently. thanks for your prompt answering

Comment: your answer is almost correct, except the file object.

Comment: If my answer is almost correct, then I helped you to get in the right way. By the way, don't beg for upvotes nor un-downvotes. Moreover, I haven't voted on this question neither up or nor down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179852/discussion-between-user1272269-and-nikolas).